# Numpy, apply a list of functions along array dimension

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I have a list of functions of the type:

```
func_list = [lambda x: function1(input),
             lambda x: function2(input),
             lambda x: function3(input),
             lambda x: x]
```

and an array of shape [4, 200, 200, 1] (a batch of images).

I want to apply the list of functions, in order, along the 0th axis.

EDIT: Rephrasing the problem. This is equivalent to the above. Say, instead of the array, I have a tuple of 4 identical arrays, of shape (200, 200, 1), and I want to apply function1 on the first element, function2 on the second element, etc. Can this be done without a for loop?

Comment: Just to understand, you want to apply it over a particular row? Axis? Or over the entire matrix? Do these functions transform each element or are they something like sum/max functions which give a single output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over your function list using `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ranom.randn(100, 100)
for f in fun_list:
    x = np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, x)
```

#### Based on OP's Update

Assuming your functions and batches are the same in size:

```
batch = ... # tuple of 4 images  
batch_out = tuple([np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, x) for f, x in zip(fun_list, batch)])
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid a for loop ?

Comment: @Qubix It'd be a good feature to have if there was a way. But I'm not sure there is.

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Coldspeed's answer, and it does work (so I will accept it) but here is an alternative I found, without using for loops:

```
result = tuple(map(lambda x,y:x(y), functions, image_tuple))
```

Edit: forgot to add the tuple(), thanks @Coldspeed

Comment: If using python 3, don't forget to tack on `tuple()` to the final answer.

Comment: `[x(y) for x, y in zip(functions, image_tuple)]` is the comprehension equivalent.