# Python Numpy Outer Product Apply List Of Functions To List Of Arguments Without For Loops

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an array of numbers, and a list of functions.

I want to run every function on every number to get back a matrix.

Is there a way to do it without slow python for looping / mapping?

```py
import numpy
    arr = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
    fns = [numpy.sin, numpy.cos, numpy.exp]
    results = numpy.zeros(shape=( len(fns), len(arr) ))
    for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
        for j, val in enumerate(arr):
            results[i][j] = fn(val)
    print ('results', results)
```

I can get rid of one loop with function broadcasting:

```py
results2 = numpy.zeros(shape=( len(fns), len(arr) ))
    for i, fn in enumerate(fns):
        results2[i] = fn(arr)
    print ('results2', results2)
```

Is there some clever pythonic numpy-ish way to get rid of my second loop?

Perhaps some built in outer-product-ish interaction which is difficult to google?

```py
results3 = numpy.function_outer( fns, arr)
```

Comment: Numpy does not know how to vectorize ```fns```. You could create a lambda function and use numpy's ```frompyfunc``` or ```apply_along_axis```, but this will just marginally slow things down.

Comment: I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614254/numpy-apply-a-list-of-functions-along-array-dimension that is related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and transform it back to a numpy array like this:

```
results3 = numpy.array([ fn(arr) for fn in fns])
```

Comment: This is cleaner to write, but not faster as it's still a `for` loop.

Comment: I cannot agree, since this is a pythonic way, as it was requested.

Comment: "Is there a way to do it without slow python for looping / mapping?"

Comment: @RandomGuy It depends on what you mean by slow. By my measurement the solution int the answer takes 5.84 µs ± 257 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each). It is a less than half the time compared to the solution with classical loop.

Comment: The author expected a numpy function like `apply_along_axis` to do so, but after some researchs it seems it is simply not possible. Moreover I tried your solution but I did not measure any significant difference between the two execution times, could you please provide a piece of your code so I can compare?

Comment: Yes, this was an idea, I've read this. On the other hand, the author expected a "pythonic numpy-ish" way. I've provided the best solution I could.