# How to vectorize a 2 level loop in NumPy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Based on the comments, I have revised the example:

Consider the following code

```py
import numpy as np

def subspace_angle(A, B):
    M = A.T @ B
    s = np.linalg.svd(M, compute_uv=False)
    return s[0]

def principal_angles(bases):    
    k = bases.shape[0]
    r = np.zeros((k, k))
    for i in range(k):
        x = bases[i]
        r[i, i] = subspace_angle(x, x)
        for j in range(i):
            y = bases[j]
            r[i, j] = subspace_angle(x, y)
            r[j, i] = r[i, j]
    r = np.minimum(1, r)
    return np.rad2deg(np.arccos(r))
```

Following is an example use:

```py
bases = []
# number of subspaces
k = 5
# ambient dimension
n = 8
# subspace dimension
m = 4
for i in range(5):
    X = np.random.randn(n, m)
    Q,R = np.linalg.qr(X)
    bases.append(Q)
# combine the orthonormal bases for all the subspaces
bases = np.array(bases)
# Compute the smallest principal angles between each pair of subspaces.
print(np.round(principal_angles(bases), 2))
```

Is there a way to avoid the two-level for loops in the `principal_angles` function, so that the code could be sped up?
As a result of this code, the matrix r is symmetric. Since `subspace_angle` could be compute-heavy depending on the array size, it is important to avoid computing it twice for `r[i,j]` and `r[j,i]`.

On the comment about JIT, actually, I am writing the code with Google/JAX. The two-level loop does get JIT compiled giving performance benefits. However, the JIT compilation time is pretty high (possibly due to two levels of for-loop). I am wondering if there is a better way to write this code so that it may compile faster.

Comment: The important question is, what kind of computation will you perform in func? can it be vectorized?

Comment: it would be some NumPy-based computation. Yes, it should be possible to vectorize it.  The particular function I have in mind is given A, B, compute M = A.T @ B, and then return the largest singular value of M. I guess that can be vectorized. I have kept a as a 2D array in the code above. But my actual use case is a being an array of matrices.

Comment: In my mind, I am looking for some way to form n(n-1)/2 pairs of rows of A, run func on each pair, then reformat the result into a triangular matrix, and finally symmetrize the triangular matrix, somehow. Wondering if such a mechanism exists.

Comment: As i see your example, the most work will need to be done in vectorizing `func`. The other lines in your code are just memory operations and might not be necessary if `func` is defined properly. It really depends on what `func` should do in the end.

Comment: as A and B are 1D arrays, shouldn't A.T@B = A@B and return a scalar? or did you mean array multiplication? Then what about using broadcasting: `np.multiply(a, a[:, None]).max(2)`?

Comment: Please provide a better example (input and expected output)

Comment: Something to clarify: python defined functions including those calling numpy routines can't be vectorized by numpy alone. Function func will be run by CPython the way it is for each element. Numpy has no way to compile things on fly.

You can achieve significant speedups using Numba http://numba.pydata.org/ - which is JIT for Python/Numpy - or perhaps Cython if you prefer.

Comment: Have revised the example code. Hopefully, it is now clearer.

Comment: `vectorize` in  the `numpy` world means replace the python-level loops with calls to compiled numpy methods that work on the whole array (or significant slices).  That requires using the multidimensional features of functions/methods like `matmul` and `svd`.  Trying to 'save time' by evaluating a triangular subset of values isn't easy or even possible.

Comment: I believe this is directly related to my older question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381195/python-numpy-outer-product-apply-list-of-functions-to-list-of-arguments-without 
I eagerly await an answer if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I started to copy your code to `ipython` session, getting a (5,8,4) shaped `bases`.  But then realized that `func` is undefined.  So by commenting that out, I get:

```
In [6]: def principal_angles(bases):
   ...:     k = bases.shape[0]
   ...:     r = np.zeros((k, k))
   ...:     for i in range(k):
   ...:         x = bases[i]
   ...:         # r[i, i] = func(x, x)
   ...:         for j in range(i):
   ...:             y = bases[j]
   ...:             r[i, j] = subspace_angle(x, y)
   ...:             #r[j, i] = r[i, j]
   ...:     return r
   ...:     #r = np.minimum(1, r)
   ...:     #return np.rad2deg(np.arccos(r))
   ...: 
In [7]: r=principal_angles(bases)
In [8]: r.shape
Out[8]: (5, 5)
```

Since both `matmul` and `svd` can work with higher dimensions, i.e. batches, I wonder if it's possible to call `subspace_angle` with all `bases`, rather than iteratively.

We have to think carefully about what shapes we pass it, and how they evolve.

```
def subspace_angle(A, B):
    M = A.T @ B
    s = np.linalg.svd(M, compute_uv=False)
    return s[0]
```

(Oops, my os just crashed the terminal, so I'll have get back to this later.)

So `A` and `B` are (8,4), `A.T` is (4,8), and `A.T@B` is (4,4)

If they were (5,8,4), `A.transpose(0,2,1)` would be (5,4,8), and `M` would be (5,4,4).

I believe `np.linalg.svd` accepts that `M`, returning a (5,4,4)

```
In [29]: r=principal_angles(bases)
In [30]: r
Out[30]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.99902153, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.99734371, 0.95318936, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.99894054, 0.99790422, 0.87577343, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.99840093, 0.92809283, 0.99896121, 0.98286429, 0.        ]])
```

Let's try that with the whole bases.  Use broadcasting to get the 'outer' product on the first dimension:

```
In [31]: M=bases[:,None,:,:].transpose(0,1,3,2)@bases
In [32]: r1=np.linalg.svd(M, compute_uv=False)
In [33]: M.shape
Out[33]: (5, 5, 4, 4)
In [34]: r1.shape
Out[34]: (5, 5, 4)
```

To match your `s[0]` I have to use (need to review the `svd` docs):

```
In [35]: r1[:,:,0]
Out[35]: 
array([[1.        , 0.99902153, 0.99734371, 0.99894054, 0.99840093],
       [0.99902153, 1.        , 0.95318936, 0.99790422, 0.92809283],
       [0.99734371, 0.95318936, 1.        , 0.87577343, 0.99896121],
       [0.99894054, 0.99790422, 0.87577343, 1.        , 0.98286429],
       [0.99840093, 0.92809283, 0.99896121, 0.98286429, 1.        ]])
```

time savings aren't massive, but may be better if the first dimension is larger than 5:

```
In [36]: timeit r=principal_angles(bases)
320 µs ± 554 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [37]: %%timeit
    ...: M=bases[:,None,:,:].transpose(0,1,3,2)@bases
    ...: r1=np.linalg.svd(M, compute_uv=False)[:,:,0]
    ...: 
    ...: 
190 µs ± 450 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This may be enough to get you started with a more refined "vectorization".

Comment: My bad. While I was revising the example code in a Jupyter session, I mistakenly left a reference to func(). I have corrected that in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I wrote the same with google Jax and it worked as expected. By avoiding the 2 for loops, the JIT compilation time reduced significantly from 22 seconds to less than 100ms.  However, post JIT compilation, the speed of the code is somewhat slower than the original one (about 20%).  I guess the main reason is that we are doing unnecessary computations. Since r[i,j] = r[j,i], hence, half of the computation can be avoided in the loop version. Is it possible to avoid it in vectorized version?

Comment: Actually for this problem, it is known that r[i,i] = 1. So the diagonal elements don't even need to be computed. Only (strict) upper or lower triangular part of r needs to be computed.

Comment: In custom compiled code, you can refine the itereation.  But using the stock building blocks as I do, you can't.  In special cases such as `A.T@A` `matmul` can detect a symmetric case, calling a faster BLAS routine, but I don't think that's relevant here.  In general trying to avoid redundant salculations in numpy doesn'tvseem to be worth theveffort.

Comment: I haven't tried to figure out why you seemingly throw away some results with the `s[0]` step. Could `svd` be called in someway to eliminate that step?

Comment: Here, I am concerned only with the smallest principal angle between two subspaces of a larger ambient space.  For a pair of subspaces, the smallest principal angle is given by the arc-cos of the largest singular value of M = A^H B where A and B are orthonormal bases for the subspaces.  That's why using only s[0].

Comment: An iterative SVD computation routine which only returns the largest singular value would be helpful. May be based on some Krylov subspace iterations. I haven't done that in this simple example code.

Answer (score 0):

After some more thinking and experimenting with `np.triu_indices` function, I have come up with the following solution which avoids extra unnecessary computation.

```py
def vectorized_principal_angles(subspaces):
    # number of subspaces
    n = subspaces.shape[0]
    # Indices for upper triangular matrix
    i, j = np.triu_indices(n, k=1)
    # prepare all the possible pairs of A and B
    A = subspaces[i]
    B = subspaces[j]
    # Compute the Hermitian transpose of each matrix in A array
    AH = np.conjugate(np.transpose(A, axes=(0,2,1)))
    # Compute M = A^H B for each matrix pair
    M = np.matmul(AH, B)
    # Compute the SVD for each matrix in M
    s = np.linalg.svd(M, compute_uv=False)
    # keep only the first singular value for each M
    s = s[:, 0]
    # prepare the result matrix
    # It is known in advance that diagonal elements will be 1.
    r = 0.5 * np.eye(n)
    r[i, j] = s
    # Symmetrize the matrix
    r = r + r.T
    # Final result
    return r
```

Here is what is going on:

- `np.triu_indices(k, k=1)` gives me indices for n(n-1)/2 pairs of possible combinations of matrices.
- All the remaining computation is limited to the n(n-1)/2 pairs only.
- Finally, the scalar values array is put back into a square symmetric result matrix

Thank you @hpaulj for your solution. It helped me a lot in getting the right direction.